# CGImageDestinationCreateWithData constants in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-image

I have the following code which turns a `CGImage` into `NSData`:

```
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics
import ImageIO
// ... snip ...
    let data = NSMutableData()
    if let dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(data, kUTTypePNG, 1, nil), let image = self.backgroundImage {
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest, image, nil)
        if CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest) {
            return data as Data
        }
    }
    return nil
```

The code compiles fine in Mac-OS, but `kUTTypePNG` is undefined in iOS. The actual value of the constant is `"public.png"`, and obviously, replacing the constant with that value allows iOS to compile the code fine.

But avoiding magic strings/numbers is the reason we use constants in the first place - is there an alternative constant in Swift-iOS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Mobile Core Services Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/CoreServicesLayer/CoreServicesLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH10-SW20) in the "iOS Technology Overview":

> The Mobile Core Services framework (MobileCoreServices.framework) defines the low-level types used in uniform type identifiers (UTIs).
>
> For more information about the types defined by this framework, see [Uniform Type Identifiers Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009257).

So

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

makes

```
public let kUTTypePNG: CFString
```

and other UTI  constants available to your code.