# How can I convert image to progressive JPEG in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, core-graphics, core-image

In my project I need to convert images of any format to progressive JPEG. How can I achieve that?

I tried like this but it does not work.

```
let sourceImage = UIImage(named: "example.jpg")
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
let url = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault,paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("progressive.jpg") as CFString  , nil)
let destinationRef = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, nil)
let jfifProperties = NSDictionary(dictionary: [kCGImagePropertyJFIFIsProgressive:kCFBooleanTrue])
let properties = NSDictionary(dictionary: [kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality:0.6,kCGImagePropertyJFIFDictionary:jfifProperties])
CGImageDestinationAddImage(destinationRef!, (sourceImage?.CGImage)!, properties)
CGImageDestinationFinalize(destinationRef!)
```

Comment: What's the error? If it is the constants, check out this answer to a similar question I asked... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916484/cgimagedestinationcreatewithdata-constants-in-ios

Comment: No it does not give error. There is no problem with constants. But problem is it does not give output.

Comment: Actually I get an error message when testing your code: `CGDataConsumer(url_close): write failed.`

Comment: @EricAya Did you find the solution?

Comment: Nope, I tried several options but I can't make this work. It's weird because `let done = CGImageDestinationFinalize(destinationRef!); print(done)` prints "true". But nothing is written and the error message pops up.

Comment: @EricAya Thank you for your help. If we can not write the file, can you make the code such that we will be able to upload to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a problem because of incorrectly defined URL.The following code works successfully on swift 2.2

```
 let sourceImage = UIImage(named: "example.jpg")
    let path = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("progressive.jpg")
    let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path as String, isDirectory: true)
    let url = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault,fileUrl.absoluteString as CFString  , nil)
    let destinationRef = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, nil)
    let jfifProperties = NSDictionary(dictionary: [kCGImagePropertyJFIFIsProgressive:kCFBooleanTrue])
    let properties = NSDictionary(dictionary: [kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality:0.6,kCGImagePropertyJFIFDictionary:jfifProperties])
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destinationRef!, (sourceImage?.CGImage)!, properties)
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(destinationRef!)
```